How to patch sink drainage pipes into wall?
There are mouse droppings in the cabinet under my kitchen sink. The mouse has has torn open a bunch of plastic wrapped bottles in the cabinet. We think that the mouse or mice entered through the hole surrounding the drainage pipe of the kitchen sink. The gap between the pipe and the wall is definitely large enough. One time, we even chased the mouse into the under sink cabinet, and when we opened the cabinet door, it was no where to be seen. So we think it escaped through that gap as well.
Question is: what am I supposed to use to fill the gap between the drainage pipe and the wall? Should it be metal grate? Or foam? Or what?




Start with the mousetraps in the cabinet. Kill and remove the ones you can get, then deal with stopping the next ones.

Stuff coarse steel wool in there, then use a hard-setting plaster patch all around the pipe. Rats and mice don't like to chew through steel wool.

I would carefully check the rest of the interior of this cabinet, as well as the adjoining ones. The poor workmanship around this pipe suggests that other instances of poor workmanship may also exist in the room. Any gap(s) between a cabinet floor and its wall, or holes that allow the passage of wires or pipes, can provide access to mice and rats. It would be prudent to remove and inspect behind big appliances (dishwasher, stove) as well.

@DavidRecallsMonica what is poor about about the workmanship? The fact that there are gaps around it? Or other things like the caulking? Just asking for future reference

The unfilled gaps around the pipe through which rodents may pass is poor workmanship. You may well find other similar instances in other places in the cabinetry. In my own kitchen, for instance, I found gaps which enabled creatures to pass from inside the wall into a storage cabinet, then another that allowed them access from the storage cabinet into the space under the stove.

You can fill the gap with rodent proof foam sealant.
I used the same for a similar issue. Solved the problem.
